# Get a subset of information from a list based on another list?

Tags: c#

I have been wondering how to accomplish a certain task for a while now and I cannot seem to be able to crack it. I'm wondering if anyone can help, assuming the task is possible at all.

Say I have two lists, one containing the statuses of certain tasks and another containing the task IDs (the lists are of the same size and the indexes are relational to each other, i.e. index 0 on task status list will be relational to index 0 on task ID list).

```
var taskStatuses = new List<string>() { "Accept", "Pending", "Reject", "Pending", "Accept" };
var taskIDs = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Is it possible to get the task IDs from the taskIDs list that only are relational to a "Pending" task status? So a new list of type int will be generated that only contains the task IDs 2 & 4.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: The question is phrased in a slightly different way, but it's really the same problem, and with the same solution. Also, you might want to try to avoid getting into this situation in the first place: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx - it may not be possible in your case, of course.

Comment: This is a good enough example of using [`Dictionary<int,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), where `Key` would be the `TaskID` and Value would be Task details. If you really have to use two `List<T>` for that then you can use `Select` overload which takes an index as parameter.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the Zip shoutout, this works, albeit in a pretty hacky way: `var pendingTasks = taskIDs.Zip(taskStatuses, (i, s) => (s == "Pending") ? i : -1);`. I can then foreach around pendingTasks and run code on anything that isn't -1.

Comment: @nabir: I wouldn't do it like that. I'd use `var pendingTasks = taskIDs.Zip(taskStatuses, (id, status) => new { id, status }).Where(pair => pair.status == "Pending").Select(pair => pair.id);`